# XAMPP Permissions On Linux

Tags: codeigniter, permissions, xampp

Recently I set-up XAMPP on Linux (POP OS 20.10) & needed to run the following in order to be able to move files into `/opt/lampp/htdocs`:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

When I did the above, functions like `fwrite()` weren't working, so I ran:

```
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-project
```

..that fixed the above `fwrite()` issue, but then I couldn't save from VS Code.

... I've also run:

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-project -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
find /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-project -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Additionally, CodeIgniter doesn't seem to be writing anything to `~/application/logs`

What permissions do I need to set so that:

1. PHP can write files?
2. CI outputs/writes to logs?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions for each directory should be 0755 and for each .php file 0644.

Example:
`sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs/my-project`